# Angular display value from json on page

Tags: json, angular

If my json looks something like this

```
    contactsCtrl.accounts = [
        {
            "id":"7363h33",
            "name":"Red Name",
            "addresses":[
                {
                    "id":"fhdydrtd-2348",
                    "line1":null,
                    "line2":null,
                    "town":null,
                    "county":null,
                    "zipcode":"AL6 TG8"
                }
            ],
            "packages":[
                {
                    "accountId":"234234",
                    "id":"345345-sehwer-wer"

                }
            ],
```

And in my html

```
    {{account.name}}
```

give me the correct name, and

```
    {{account.packages}}
```

shows me json for packages. How can I get just the id in packages. I'v tried

```
    {{account.packages.id}}
```

Comment: packages is an array, so `account.packages[0].id` if you only have one item, otherwise you need to iterate the packages as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I use `{{accounts.packages[0]?.id}}` to make sure it finds the right value. Without the `?`, the html will error as it doesn't usually like having `[]`

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
 
 $scope.accounts = [
  {
    "id": "7363h33",
    "name": "Red Name",
    "addresses": [
      {
        "id": "fhdydrtd-2348",
        "line1": null,
        "line2": null,
        "town": null,
        "county": null,
        "zipcode": "AL6 TG8"
      }
    ],
    "packages": [
      {
        "accountId": "234234",
        "id": "345345-sehwer-wer"
      }
    ]
  }
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="x in accounts">
    <span>{{ x.name }}</span>
     <div ng-repeat="package in x.packages">
     <span>{{package.id}} </span>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do an ng-repeat over packages,

```
 <div ng-repeat="x in accounts">
    <h1>{{ x.name }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ x.phonenumber }}</h1>
     <div ng-repeat="package in x.packages">
     <h2>{{package.id}} </h2>
     </div
  </div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("AccountsController", function($scope) {
 
 $scope.accounts = [
  {
    "id": "7363h33",
    "name": "Red Name",
    "addresses": [
      {
        "id": "fhdydrtd-2348",
        "line1": null,
        "line2": null,
        "town": null,
        "county": null,
        "zipcode": "AL6 TG8"
      }
    ],
    "packages": [
      {
        "accountId": "234234",
        "id": "345345-sehwer-wer"
      }
    ]
  }
];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AccountsController">
<table>
  <div ng-repeat="x in accounts">
    <h1>{{ x.name }}</h1>
    <h1>{{ x.phonenumber }}</h1>
     <div ng-repeat="package in x.packages">
     <h2>{{package.id}} </h2>
     </div
  </div>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```